# OOP in python programming, I keep getting an error message about defining main()

Tags: python

```
def main():
    name = input("What would you like to name your character?")
    print("Your character has been created!")
    play = Player(name)



class Player():
    """A game player"""



    def __init__(self, name, items, max_items = 7):
        self.__name = name
        self.__items = []
        self.__max_items = 7


    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name


    def charInfo(self):
        print("This is your character's name:", self.__name)

    def inventory(self):
        if len(self.__items) > 7:
            print ("Your iventory is:")
            print (self.__items)
        else:
            print("There's nothing in your inventory.")

    def take(self, add_item):
        if self.__items <= self.__max_items:
            self.__items.append(add_item)
        else:
            print("You already have the max items in your inventory,sorry")

    def drop(self, drop_item):
        if drop_item not in self.__items:
            print("That item isn't in your inventory.")
        else:
            self.__items.remove(drop_item)

choice = None
while choice != 0:

    print(""" Character Menu
            0 - Quit
            1 - Character Information
            2 - Inventory
            3 - Add an item
            4 - Drop an item""")

    choice = input("What would you like to do?")

    #Exit
    if choice == "0":
        print("See you later!")

    #Character Information
    elif choice == "1":
        play.charInfo()

    #Inventory
    elif choice == "2":
        play.inventory()

    #Add an item
    elif choice == "3":
        add_item = input("What would you like to add to your inventory?")
        add_item = add_item.lower()
        play.take(add_item)

    #Drop an item
    elif choice == "4":
        drop_item = input("What item would you like to drop?")
        drop_item = drop_item.lower()
        play.drop(drop_item)

main()
input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

I keep getting this error message and I'm not understanding why. It looks to me as if I've defined the main(). I'm trying to see if someone can help me understand why I'm getting this error message. I'm new to python

Comment: what are you expecting `main()` to do?

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python31/play.py", line 68, in <module>
    play.charInfo()
NameError: name 'play' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `main()` outside of the class `Player()`.
**Edit:**
Your code will work this way:

```
def main():
    name = input("What would you like to name your character?")
    print("Your character has been created!")
    play = Player(name)
    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print(""" Character Menu
            0 - Quit
            1 - Character Information
            2 - Inventory
            3 - Add an item
            4 - Drop an item""")
        choice = input("What would you like to do?")
        #Exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("See you later!")
        #Character Information
        elif choice == "1":
            play.charInfo()
        #Inventory
        elif choice == "2":
            play.inventory()
        #Add an item
        elif choice == "3":
            add_item = input("What would you like to add to your inventory?")
            add_item = add_item.lower()
            play.take(add_item)
        #Drop an item
        elif choice == "4":
            drop_item = input("What item would you like to drop?")
            drop_item = drop_item.lower()
            play.drop(drop_item)


class Player():
    """A game player"""



    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
        self.__items = []
        self.__max_items = 7


    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name


    def charInfo(self):
        print("This is your character's name:", self.__name)

    def inventory(self):
        if len(self.__items) > 7:
            print ("Your iventory is:")
            print (self.__items)
        else:
            print("There's nothing in your inventory.")

    def take(self, add_item):
        if len(self.__items) <= self.__max_items:
            self.__items.append(add_item)
        else:
            print("You already have the max items in your inventory,sorry")

    def drop(self, drop_item):
        if drop_item not in self.__items:
            print("That item isn't in your inventory.")
        else:
            self.__items.remove(drop_item)

main()

input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: well yeah I figured that out, now I have another error message

Comment: @DBB, The class `Player()` also takes one argument (name).

Comment: Yeah I passed (name, items, and max_items) to it but I still get that same error message

Comment: @DBB, It takes only one argument which is name, it should be like this `Player(name)`, I could help you better if you tell me what's the error.

Comment: Ok that part I just figured out. Saw that information in my book but now I get (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python31/play.py", line 70, in <module>
    play.inventory()
NameError: name 'play' is not defined

Comment: This happens for every one of my functions that I've defined

Comment: @DBB, Are you placing `play.inventory()` after or before `play = Player(name)`? You changed the code, I don't know how the new code looks like.

Comment: @DBB, you messed your code up a bit, but now I think it will work.

Comment: Well actually just the add function

Comment: @DBB, The problem was in the `take()` method in your `Player()` class, I fixed it, you should learn to fix these kinds of problems yourself, they're really simple.

Comment: well yes I seen how to fix that problem

Answer (score 3):

You defined `main` inside the `Player` class, so it only exists as a method on a `Player` object (where it will be uncallable, because it takes no arguments).

You need to outdent it, to top-level, before you can call it.

Also: don't use `self.__foo` for attribute names.  It doesn't make them private, it's really weird to read, and it mostly just gives you grief.  Use `self._foo` if you must, but unless you have a really good reason to hide your state, just use `self.foo`.

Comment: There's a reason I'm using it that way. The professor wants us to do it out of the book that way. I corrected the main() problem but now I have another error

Comment: your professor is wrong.  also, you removed the `def main` entirely, so now it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: oh, sorry, i see.  well now you're doing the `while` loop _before_ you call `main`, so the player object doesn't exist yet.